# Background image property not working in react css

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I'm trying to show the background image using css in react. I have stored all the images in an assets folder. All the image files are stored locally.
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU1fp.png)

Whenever I'm trying to show the image in the background, its not working.

```
    .hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("../assets/1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

[Local images not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdEk2.png)

But if i use external image link. Then its working.

```
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528127269322-539801943592?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

[external images are working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57FWz.png)

Do you guys have any solution for that?
'

Comment: check this out - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-background-image-tutorial-how-to-set-backgroundimage-with-inline-css-style/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to image format. If you change your locale image to another, it works. Try to change the image to another for testing. I recommend **png** format.